# Dependent Spinner using webservice

Tags: android, web-services, android-spinner

I used two spinners, country and state which i get from web-service. 
i get Country in first web-service then i should pass selected country from spinner to the second web-service, How can i call the dependent Spinner in Web-service  ? 
Give me the example,
Thanks.

### First Spinner

```
int i = 0;
        String[] stringArray = new String[List.length];



        for (i = 0; i < List.length; i++) {
        stringArray[i] = Arrays.asList(List[i].Country);
        }

        Spinner spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);


        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray);
        adapter1.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);

        spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
});
```

Comment: What do you mean by "call the dependent Spinner in web service"? Be more specific with your request.

Comment: if i select country in spinner(first web-service) it pass the selected value to second web-service then i get response(State) in second spinner.

Comment: What is the question; do you want to know how to receive a response from an API call? I assume you know that if you already successfully loaded values from an API response into the first spinner.

Comment: i need to call the second web-service when country is selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same query some days back I guess this will solve your problem.

Add this after your spinner1 code

```
 // here onitemselected call your second method 


@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
View view, int pos, long id) {
statewebservice((String) parent.getItemAtPosition(pos));

}
```

And for state spinner in your second web service

```
int i = 0;
String[] stringArray2 = new String[List2.length];


for (i = 0; i < personList1.length; i++) {
stringArray2[i] = Arrays.asList(List2[i].State);

}

Spinner spinner2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter2 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, stringArray2);
            adapter2.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);

spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {


@Override
public void onItemSelected(final AdapterView<?> parent,
View view, final int pos1, long id) {

//************Code after selecting second spinner ***********

}

});

}
```